# Constructing datetime from 2 fields: one integer and a datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I am looking for the most efficient way to parse 2 values; the first is stored as a datetime field with (hh:mm:ss.fff all being 0) and the second time field stored as an int with the format: hhmmssmmm). I need to take these 2 fields and convert them to a datetime field. For example:

```
date field = '2013-09-04'
time field = 192423998
```

Should return:

```
2013-09-04 19:24:23.997
```

[I've seen solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718880/sql-convert-int-to-time) using DATEADD and CONVERT and I came up with my own (shown below) but I wonder if there's a better/more efficient way.

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2013-09-04'

SELECT  @dt+' '+ STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0'+CAST(192423998 AS VARCHAR(9)),9)  ,7,0,'.'),5,0,':'),3,0,':')
```

Note: In case you wonder why the `RIGHT('0'+CAST(192423998 AS VARCHAR(9)),9)` - this is because a time before 10 AM will only have one digit for the hour part.

Comment: Have you considered fixing the design?

Comment: @AaronBertrand That is not a possibility. The database has billions of rows of trading data and several apps (matching and routing engines) write to the database using an int to represent the time of the day :-/

Comment: If you paid someone to design this system, you should ask for a partial refund for (a) all of the wasted space and (b) your troubles.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Refund? That person(s) needs to pay for damages...  Seriously though, the saddest part is that it was likely a decision made by either the "chief software architect" or worse, a group of senior developers. In any case, I don't want to know... :-/

Comment: Is SQLCLR on the table? Design issues aside, I'd be curious to compare a CLR solution against a T-SQL solution.

Comment: @JonSeigel CLR integration is not enabled, unfortunately. I thought about that possibility too.

Comment: @JonSeigel I created a SQL CLR Function to test on my DEV environment (used DateTime.TryParseExact) and on 100K rows sample, performs twice slower than my T-SQL version (3s Vs 6 secs).

Comment: @JonSeigel Getting rid of `TryParseExact` and using `ParseExact` only reduced the execution time by 1 sec (5 secs). Still slower than the T-SQL approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you're going to be parsing strings and ints and doing all kinds of conversions, so I don't think you're going to really save anything by seeking out a "more efficient" way to turn crap data into good data - even on billions of rows. An alternative might be to avoid converting anything to a string at all (which is notoriously bad for performance):

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '20130904', @t INT = 192423998;

SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @t % 100000 -- milliseconds
  + 60000 * (@t / 100000 % 100) -- minutes converted to milliseconds
  + 60000 * 60 * (@t / 10000000), -- hours converted to milliseconds
  @dt);
```

Of course, keep in mind that the milliseconds your trading system passes in can round in either direction when using datetime (.998 isn't possible and becomes .997, for example), so you may want instead:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @t % 100000 -- milliseconds
  + 60000 * (@t / 100000 % 100) -- minutes converted to milliseconds
  + 60000 * 60 * (@t / 10000000), -- hours converted to milliseconds
  CONVERT(DATETIME2(3), @dt));
```

I ran these each 100,000 times, and compared to your existing approach. The difference?

```
Your approach:               41.8 seconds
My approach (no convert):    40.5 seconds
My approach (with convert):  38.9 seconds
```

Now, this should not be extrapolated to mean that on 1 billion rows my method will save you (13,000 or 31,000) seconds, as the translation of 100,000 batches to operating on 100,000 rows in a single statement will not be linear. But it could be worth testing (you have the data necessary to test this; I would just be making stuff up, and I also probably have processors that have different performance characteristics when it comes to floating point operations etc., so anything else I could offer would not necessarily be relevant).

I still think you're better off taking the hit, fixing the design, and intercepting the incoming trading data and correcting it. As this system gets bigger, these translations and conversions are going to hurt more, and more, and more...